# How to import models from one app to another app in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to reference a model (Person) from one app, in the views-file of another app. Unfortunately, I get an "unresolved reference"-error. Is it possible to reference models from other apps in Django? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Let me demonstrate with an example:

The image below shows my project. I am currently in the views.py (marked in green), in the app called "autocomplete". I want to reference a person-model in the file "models.py" (marked in red), that belongs to the app "resultregistration". However, I get the error "Unresolved reference Person", even though the class Person does exist in models.py

[image]

The file settings.py is in the athlitikos/athlitikos - folder, and manage.py is in only athlitikos (as seen in the image below)

[image]

Any help would be strongly appreciated!

**Edit:** I now tried running "from ..resultregistration.models import Person", because I saw that what I did in the screenshot was obviously wrong. However, then I get the error message " attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It'd be better to copy the code instead of making a screenshot.

Comment: It might be better but not a reason to downvote it, question is well made and well explained

Comment: I didn't downvote it. I almost never downvote, even really bad questions. By the way, you can use the command `tree` to display the directory structure. The output can be posted here.

Comment: Yeah, wasnt blaming you, but someone downvoted him probably due the screenshot and thats absurd

Comment: @lapinkoira Absolutely, the questions is very well formed and clear. Whoever downvoted, please reconsider your action. It's a shame if we dishonour the effort and discourage people participating in SO.

Comment: It is a good practice to group the imports and separate them with a blank line. First make the imports from django, than blank line, then imports from your project.

Comment: I assume you have `__init__.py` in every `athlitikos` and every directory below, don't you?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have an __init__.py in every athlitikos

Comment: Now, after the update, I see you won't really need the `__init__.py` in the top directory `athlitikos`.

Answer (score 8):

If the `resultregistration` app is in the project directory (the one containing `manage.py`) then you shouldn't include the project name `athlitikos` in the import at all. Try the following:

```
from resultregistration.models import Person
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the reply. This worked in PyCharm, but when I did manage.py runserver, I got the error: "unresolved reference resultregistration". I also tried "from ..resultregistration.models import Person", but get the error "attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

Comment: Which directories are `manage.py` and `settings.py` in? It's not clear from your screenshot.

Comment: I added another screenshot now, manage.py is under athlitikos, and settings.py is under athlitikos/athlitikos

Comment: I'm afraid don't know why it's not working for you. In particular, I'm very surprised that `./manage.py runserver` gives the error `unresolved reference resultregistration`.

Comment: That is ok! Thank you so much for your time either way. Also, it probably does not help much, but it is not manage.py runserver, that gives the error "unresolved reference resultregistration". It is actually PyCharm right when I write the code

Comment: It sounds like the `from resultregistration.models import Person` import is correct, but the Python path is not properly configured in PyCharm.

Answer (score 3):

mm why you repeat athlitikos?, try replacing:

```
from athlitikos.athlitikos.resultregistration.models import Person
```

with

```
from resultregistration.models import Person
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! :D That is because our project has a main folder athlitikos, that has another folder athlitikos in it (the one you see in the image) 

When I remove one athlitikos, as you suggested, I get a new error saying "no module named athlitikos.resultregistration"

Comment: well then leave just, resultregistration, athilikos is project name I suppose

Answer (score 2):

When doing the import from pycharm, it starts looking from the level of your present file, which is `autocomplete/views.py`, but Django starts from the project level, which is the level of your `manage.py`, so you can use `from resultregistration.models import Person` directly. Even though pycharm's inspections will show you errors in the code, it will pass when you running the project.

Answer (score 1):

If we analyse your directory tree, we can see that:

```
athlitikos
    autocomplete
        views.py
    resultregistration
        models.py
```

In the `views.py` in `autocomplete` you can reference to other modules with relative path. Try this:

```
from ..resultregistration.models import Person
```

The first dot goes up to `autocomplete`, the second dot goes up to `athlitikos`. Now from there you can access `resultregistration` and everything underneath.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried that, and at least it gave me another error message, which was "attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

Comment: Now after you updated your question with another screenshot, I see `athlitikos` is the top level directory. Then the answers from Alasdair and lapinkoira should actually work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work:

```
from athlitikos.resultregistration.models import Person
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! I tried doing that, but unfortunately get the error: 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'athlitikos.resultregistration

Answer (score 0):

resultregistration.models should do it. Just make sure the app is added to the installed apps in your settings.py.