# How to import Django app from another app in same project?

Tags: django-models, python-import, importerror, django-import-export

Even though same question has been arise 20 times on Stackoverflow, but none of them exactly provide what is the actual problem.

I have few Django apps in my Django project, but when I'm trying to import model from one app to another its not importing. I tired to solve the problem in following ways but no luck:

```
backend
├── realtors
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── listings
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── accounts
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt.
└── realest-estate
    ├── asgi.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

litings.models

```
from django.db import models
from realtors.models import Realtors



class Listing(models.Model):
    class SaleType(models.TextChoices):
        FOR_SALE = 'For Sales'
        FOR_RENT = 'For Rent'

    class HomeType(models.TextChoices):
        HOUSE = 'House'
        CONDO = 'Condo'
        TOWNHOUSE = 'Townhouse'

    realtor = models.ForeignKey(Realtors, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

realtors.models

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime


class Realtors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photo/%Y/%m/%d/')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    top_seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_hired = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I tried to import the model in following ways as well, but out of luck:

```
1-)
from django.apps import apps
model = apps.get_model('realtors', 'Realtors')

2-)
from backend.realtors.models import Realtors
```

[Here is a screenshot of the error in terminal and model file where it's not importing]  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP9as.png):

Note: I'm not using pyCharam and when I print out my root directory in my settings.py by printing(BASE_DIR) it give the exact same path where it leads to the manage.py as root  C:.../.../backend
Also most realted Stakoverflow question is: [How to import models from one app to another app in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444135/how-to-import-models-from-one-app-to-another-app-in-django)

Any help? I'm stuck for days! :(

Comment: Does the app run OK?  Can you load the model in `manage.py. shell`?  Just wondering if it is only the editor which is reporting the problem.

Comment: @MatthewHegarty Thank you for the Response:
The problem wasn't in importing the module it was, indeed, the text editor causing all the trouble. The actual issue is somewhere else, in views.py. I was  sending a POST request to the SearchView, its not responding an HTTPResponse but some <NoneType> class . Idk , where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the above problem the *text editor* was creating all the problem for importing. The app is now importing the modules from another app.

But in my screenshot the terminal showing error:

> assert isinstance(response, HttpResponseBase), (
> AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`

is somehow related to my listings/views.py modules.

& Here is the views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView, ListAPIView
from rest_framework import permissions
from .models import Listing
from .serializer import ListingSerializer, ListingDetailSerializer
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta


class ListingsView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Listing.objects.order_by(
        '-list_date').filter(is_published=True)
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )
    serializer_class = ListingSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'


class ListingView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date').filter(is_published=True)
    serializer_class = ListingDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'


class SearchView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )
    serializer_class = ListingSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        queryset = Listing.objects.order_by(
            '-list_date').filter(is_published=True)

        data = self.request.data

        sale_type = data['sale_type']
        queryset = queryset.filter(sale_type__iexact=sale_type)

        price = data['price']
        if price == '$0+':
            price = 0
        elif price == '$200,000+':
            price = 200000
        elif price == '$400,000+':
            price = 400000
        elif price == '$600,000+':
            price = 600000
        elif price == '$800,000+':
            price = 800000
        elif price == '$1,000,000+':
            price = 1000000
        elif price == '$1,500,000+':
            price = 1500000
        elif price == 'Any':
            price = -1

        if price != -1:
            queryset = queryset.filter(price__gte=price)

        badrooms = data['badrooms']
        if badrooms == '0+':
            badrooms = 0
        elif badrooms == '1+':
            badrooms = 1
        elif badrooms == '2+':
            badrooms = 2
        elif badrooms == '3+':
            badrooms = 3
        elif badrooms == '4+':
            badrooms = 4
        elif badrooms == '5+':
            badrooms = 5

        queryset = queryset.filter(badrooms__gte=badrooms)

        home_type = data['home_type']
        queryset = queryset.filter(home_type__iexact=home_type)

        bathrooms = data['bathrooms']
        if bathrooms == '0+':
            bathrooms = 0.0
        elif bathrooms == '1+':
            bathrooms = 1.0
        elif bathrooms == '2+':
            bathrooms = 2.0
        elif bathrooms == '3+':
            bathrooms = 3.0
        elif bathrooms == '4+':
            bathrooms = 4.0
        elif bathrooms == '5+':
            bathrooms = 5.0

        queryset = queryset.filter(bathrooms__gte=bathrooms)

        sqft = data['sqft']
        if sqft == '1000+':
            sqft = 1000
        elif sqft == '1200+':
            sqft = 1200
        elif sqft == '1500+':
            sqft = 1500
        elif sqft == '2000+':
            sqft = 2000
        elif sqft == 'Any':
            sqft = 0

        if sqft != 0:
            queryset = queryset.filter(sqft__gte=sqft)

        days_passed = data['days_listed']
        if days_passed == '1 or less':
            days_passed = 1
        elif days_passed == '2 or less':
            days_passed = 2
        elif days_passed == '5 or less':
            days_passed = 5
        elif days_passed == '10 or less':
            days_passed = 10
        elif days_passed == '15 or less':
            days_passed = 15
        elif days_passed == '20 or less':
            days_passed = 20
        elif days_passed == 'Any':
            days_passed = 0

        for query in queryset:
            num_days = (datetime.now(timezone.utc) - query.list_date).days

            if days_passed != 0:
                if num_days > days_passed:
                    slug = query.slug
                    queryset = queryset.exclude(slug__iexact=slug)

        has_photos = data['has_photos']
        if has_photos == '1+':
            has_photos = 1
        elif has_photos == '3+':
            has_photos = 3
        elif has_photos == '5+':
            has_photos = 5
        elif has_photos == '10+':
            has_photos = 10
        elif has_photos == '15+':
            has_photos = 15

        for query in queryset:
            count = 0
            if query.photo_1:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_2:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_3:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_4:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_5:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_6:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_7:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_8:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_9:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_10:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_11:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_12:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_13:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_14:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_15:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_16:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_17:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_18:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_19:
                count += 1
            if query.photo_20:
                count += 1

            if count < has_photos:
                slug = query.slug
                queryset = queryset.exclude(slug__iexact=slug)

            open_house = data['open_house']
            queryset = queryset.filter(open_house__iexact=open_house)

            keywords = data['keywords']
            queryset = queryset.filter(description__icontains=keywords)

            serializer = ListingSerializer(queryset, many=True)

            return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Please can you post as a separate question - you are more likely to get a response that way

Answer (score 0):

```
form realtors.models import Realtors
```

make sure your apps are registered in settings.py under INSATLLED_APPS

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the app names are installed under INSATLLED_APPS in settungs.py.

Comment: is `form realtors.models import Realtors` working?

Comment: yes, its working perfectly now. Classical mistake, I forget indentation. 
Thank you for the response!